# Ansible playbook to find out specific files in sub directories

Tags: ansible

I have directory structure as below, wants to fetch the specific sub directory files using ansible rather than all.

```
/mnt/server1 ->
      ----> yyy.deb

      ----> /mnt/server1/All/tttsss.deb

      ----> /mnt/server1/HS-CLONE/gggg.deb

      ----> /mnt/server1/HS-TEST/kkkk.deb
```

I need to find only files present under `/mnt/server1/All/tttsss.deb and /mnt/server1/HS-CLONE/gggg.deb` directories. I don't require all other files.

When i trying using below logic, the parent directory file  `yyy.deb` is also coming as output.

```
- name: Ansible find files in subdirectory examples
  find:
         paths:  /mnt/server1
         file_type: file
         recurse: yes
         use_regex: yes
         patterns:
           - 'All'
           - "HS-CLONE"
           - '.*deb$'

  register: files_matched_subdirectory
```

With the above logic output as:

Output:

```
yyy.deb
/mnt/server1/All/tttsss.deb
/mnt/server1/HS-CLONE/gggg.deb
```

Expected output should be:

```
/mnt/server1/All/tttsss.deb
/mnt/server1/HS-CLONE/gggg.deb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have below specific pattern in your find command which will match `yyy.deb` in the directory `/mnt/server1`

```
patterns:
    - '.*deb$'
```

you can use `excludes` parameter to explicitly exclude this particular file :

```
- name: Ansible find files in subdirectory examples
  find:
         paths:  /mnt/server1
         file_type: file
         recurse: yes
         use_regex: yes
         patterns:
           - 'All'
           - "HS-CLONE"
           - '.*deb$'
         excludes: 
           - 'yyy.deb'
  register: files_matched_subdirectory
```

Or may be you can try something like below in your pattern parameter :

```
patterns:
  - 'All'
  - "HS-CLONE"
  - '*/.*deb$'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The above mentioned pattern doesn't work. Yes, i can excludes to omit file. But i may not know the same file be present always, the file name can be changed. Looking for the generic pattern to solve this issue. But i tested with your above pattern it doesn't work.

Comment: That might not work I just wanted to give an idea that we can actually tweak the pattern part. You can try removing asterisk before / .

Comment: Thanks.. I removed asterisk, but it is not working . Will try with different options.